# How does Powershell Auto-Load Modules?

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

We [learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-5.1) that Powershell introduced Module Auto-Loading in 3.0 :

> ... PowerShell imports modules automatically the first time that you
> run any command in an installed module. You can now use the
> **commands** in a module without any set-up or profile configuration, ...

And this is done via [PSModulePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psmodulepath?view=powershell-5.1).

What the docs fail to explain is **how** Powershell can detect **which** commands are in a module **without** first loading the module.

That is, when **I** use `Import-Module`, I "know" that Powershell will execute (??!) the powershell code in my `.psm1` file, exporting all functions, ... or whatever I spec with `Export-Modulemember`.

However, the Auto-Load feature has to know before hand that a certain command is available via a certain module **without** actually loading the module.

Since we had some misbehaving third party modules in PsModulePath and since we have a very few modules that we wrote ourselves that we like to anchor in PSModulePath, I would very much like to understand **how** the files in PSModulePath are processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

This is done/implemented via `Get-Command` and this *seems* to be enabled to "parse" module files without actually executing the PoSh Code there. See below.

From the powershell docs:

> #### [Implicitly Importing a Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/importing-a-powershell-module?view=powershell-5.1#implicitly-importing-a-module-powershell-30)
>
> ... works on any module in a directory that is included in the value
> of the PSModulePath environment variable ...
>
> To support automatic importing of modules, the `Get-Command` cmdlet
> gets all cmdlets and functions in all installed modules, even if the
> module is not imported into the session. ...

And then:

> ### [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Get-Command?view=powershell-7.3#description)
>
> The Get-Command cmdlet gets all commands that are installed on the
> computer ...
>
> `Get-Command` that uses the exact name of the command, without
> wildcard characters, automatically imports the module that contains
> the command so that you can use the command immediately. ...
>
> `Get-Command` **gets its data directly from the command code**, unlike
> ...

The docs do not explain *how* this is implemented, but one could possibly look up how it's done in the [source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/2ddc63f1512e35f8dce696ae10de49f8f69a2738/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/CommandDiscovery.cs#L1137). (I wasn't so far able to find it, despite browsing the sources for a while.)

Incidentally I find [mentioned that Powershell 3 was the first version to expose the AST](https://mikefrobbins.com/2022/04/08/use-the-abstract-syntax-tree-ast-to-inspect-powershell-command-syntax-in-scripts/), so it stands to reason that the posh code does exactly that: **Parse the Scripts and inspect their AST in *some* way to determine if the command is provided.**